# With Nix and WSL, what can cause an error of `.: File exists \n ..: File exists`?

Tags: haskell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nix

I've run into this error in a WSL shell:

```
$ nix-shell -p 'haskell.packages.ghc822.ghcWithPackages (p: with p; [text])' --run ghci -j4
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/qkbijf516579sf5654i75g0nvkyk8f08-ghc-8.2.2-with-packages.drv
building '/nix/store/qkbijf516579sf5654i75g0nvkyk8f08-ghc-8.2.2-with-packages.drv'...
.: File exists
..: File exists
.: File exists
..: File exists
lib: /nix/store/2dn56f3pvazrfqpxl9629d94v323crq2-text-1.2.2.2/lib
nix-support: /nix/store/2dn56f3pvazrfqpxl9629d94v323crq2-text-1.2.2.2/nix-support
rm: cannot remove '/nix/store/bcr5inb3vf8aazqprh216xchif8si2ia-ghc-8.2.2-with-packages/bin/ghc': Permission denied
killing process 9380: No such process
builder for '/nix/store/qkbijf516579sf5654i75g0nvkyk8f08-ghc-8.2.2-with-packages.drv' failed with exit code 1
error: build of '/nix/store/qkbijf516579sf5654i75g0nvkyk8f08-ghc-8.2.2-with-packages.drv' failed

$ nix-shell --version
nix-shell (Nix) 2.0
```

- What can cause this?
- Could it be that the WSL /nix/store is corrupted somehow?
- If so, can I repair it?
- Or is my only option to delete it and start from 0?

Edit:

I've tried `nix-store --check-contents --verify` and `nix-store --delete /nix/store/...` with all implicated store paths in the error message. Neither of them got rid of the error.

Edit 2:

- Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.309]
- Tried both under `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS` and `16.04.4`, same error.

Comment: See these issues on nixpkgs issue tracker: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/26506 https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/27808 Unfortunately it sounds like there is no working solution as of yet.